# Firebase Database retrieving objects from child node A specified in child node B

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to implement a shallow data structure in my Firebase Database. For that matter I have two child nodes. The first child node (`users`) has userIDs with a list of itemIDs from the second child node (`items`).

How do I populate a `UITableView`/`RecyclerView` with items from the item list that are specified in the user list? Each logged-in user has its own items and I want to retrieve them from the `items` list. Can it be done with FirebaseUI?

The solution can come for any supported platform, I just want to get the idea.

```js
{
  "users" : {
    "97csAjE3dIZxZ5t3LbgxbaSOgxl2" : { // userID
      "TQjEnGjiRNsYL9" : { // each key is an itemID
        "etc" : "..."
      },
      "VPHYi6xhrYsAwK" : {
        "etc" : "..."
      },
      "WbnrFVDdfB9iJj" : {
        "etc" : "..."
      },
      "xB9UgakhHkNzid" : {
        "etc" : "..."
      }
    }
  },
  "items" : [ {
    "_id" : "vCG3furXeUnZpK", // Eventually I'll make this _id into the item key
    "etc" : "..."
  }, {
    "_id" : "WbnrFVDdfB9iJj"
  }, {
    "_id" : "xB9UgakhHkNzid"
  }, {
    "_id" : "VPHYi6xhrYsAwK"
  }, {
    "_id" : "TQjEnGjiRNsYL9"
  }, {
    "_id" : "Bor6VhCyqxZHpb"
  }, {
    "_id" : "iQnMmNy2fbrvYn"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show me json data structure from firebase?

Comment: Please share a snippet of the actual JSON you're asking about (as text, which you can get by clicking the Export JSON in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)). It also would be welcome if you show what you've already tried, so that we can tie answers in to that.

Comment: @JdPrajapati I added a JSON snippet

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added a JSON snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get all the itemID for current user and store id somewhere.

```
let itemIDArray = [String]()
```

now for each item id get item detail using following code

```
// database reference
ref.child("items").child(itemID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to get data for specific user using firebase condition with child node.

```
database.child(Table).
         orderByChild("user/id")
        .equalTo("somevalue").
```